# Consider floated elements for the width of blocks

Tags: html, css, css-float, width

Imagine the following markup ([link to jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/3TYUj/)):

```
<div style="float: right; width: 200px; height: 200px; background-color: red; margin: 0 20px 0 30px;">
     Block 1
</div>

<div style="height: 100px; background-color: green;">Block 2</div>
```

Because the first block is floated, the second block takes the whole available space for the width as if block 1 is not defined. What do I need to set for the second block so that its width is maximal the space to block 1 minus the left margin of block 1?

The final result should be something like [this](http://jsfiddle.net/3TYUj/2/), where I used `display: flex` in the second block. But in my case I cannot use this solution, because the second block contains a paragraph which looks ugly with `display: flex`.

**Note:** In my case (programming a template for a wiki) I just can change the CSS of the second block!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of using `flex`, simply add `overflow: auto` to Block 2:

```
<div style="height: 100px; background-color: green; overflow: auto;">
    Block 2
</div>
```

See demo at: http://jsfiddle.net/PXuWB/

The advantage of this approach is that you don't have to specify an exact length of a margin, which is more useful in a responsive design.

By setting `overflow: auto`, you create a block-formatting context which prevents the content from interacting with any adjacent floated elements.

Reference: http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/visuren.html#block-formatting

Answer (score 2):

Give block two a right margin equal to the width and margin of block one:

```
<div style="height: 100px; background-color: green;margin-right:230px;">Block 2</div>
```

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/3TYUj/3/)**

(side note: avoid using inline CSS whenever possible)